# How to parse json objects (saved as csv) in R

Tags: html, r, transpose

So far, I have this:

```
file         responses
file1.csv    {"Q0":2, "Q1":2, "Q2":2, "Q3":2, .... "Q15":2}
file2.csv    {"Q0":2, "Q1":2, "Q2":2, "Q3":2, .... "Q15":2}
```

But the whole data of each file is is only one cell each.

I want this:

```
 Item    responses    file
 Q0      2            file1.csv
 Q1      2            file1.csv
 Q2      2            file1.csv
 ...
 Q15     2            file1.csv
 Q0      2            file2.csv
 Q1      2            file2.csv
 Q2      2            file2.csv
 ...
 Q15     2            file2.csv
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show us the script used to parse the csv files, so we can help you improve it. And avoid to link external pictures.

Comment: you mean the html script? thanks a lot!

Comment: That doesn't look like a CSV file. It looks like you have JSON data embedded in a text file. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Make it very clear exactly what "this" is (what type of object it is).

Comment: html script? I thought you were using R script. Nice point @MrFlick.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/rjson.pdf I could probably use this package but I don't know the sintax to make this operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Read each file and convert it from JSON format into the desired form.  Finally combine each one using `rbind`.

```
# create test data
cat('{"Q0":1, "Q1":2, "Q2":3, "Q3":4, "Q15":5}\n', file = "file1.csv")
cat('{"Q0":11, "Q1":12, "Q2":13, "Q3":14, "Q15":15}\n', file = "file2.csv")
Files <- c("file1.csv", "file2.csv")

library(rjson)

m <- do.call("rbind", lapply(Files, function(f) {
  x <- fromJSON(file = f)
  cbind(Item = names(x), responses = unname(unlist(x)), file = f)
}))
```

giving this character matrix:

```
> m
      Item  responses file       
 [1,] "Q0"  "1"       "file1.csv"
 [2,] "Q1"  "2"       "file1.csv"
 [3,] "Q2"  "3"       "file1.csv"
 [4,] "Q3"  "4"       "file1.csv"
 [5,] "Q15" "5"       "file1.csv"
 [6,] "Q0"  "11"      "file2.csv"
 [7,] "Q1"  "12"      "file2.csv"
 [8,] "Q2"  "13"      "file2.csv"
 [9,] "Q3"  "14"      "file2.csv"
[10,] "Q15" "15"      "file2.csv"
```

**2)** If what you meant was that your starting point is not the files themselves but a data frame `DF` with `file` and `responses` columns then:

```
# form input data frame -- this is the two columns shown in the question
DF <- data.frame(file = Files, responses = sapply(Files, readLines))

dd <- do.call("rbind", by(DF, DF$file, function(d) {
  f <- as.character(d$file)
  x <- fromJSON(json_str = as.character(d$responses))
  data.frame(Item = names(x), responses = unname(unlist(x)), file = f, 
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}))
rownames(dd) <- NULL
```

giving this data frame:

```
> dd
   Item responses      file
1    Q0         1 file1.csv
2    Q1         2 file1.csv
3    Q2         3 file1.csv
4    Q3         4 file1.csv
5   Q15         5 file1.csv
6    Q0        11 file2.csv
7    Q1        12 file2.csv
8    Q2        13 file2.csv
9    Q3        14 file2.csv
10  Q15        15 file2.csv
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I've tried out the function you gave but it attributes for example  "Q0" to 1 file for 4 times (the number of files is 4),

Comment: I have improved the input data from the data in the question which used all the same values so you can see that it does indeed work.  Have also changed the second code (starting from `DF`) to produce a data frame so there is an example of both matrix and data frame output.

Comment: thank you a lot for your kind help! Unfortunately it doesn't work. I start from a R dataframe.  f <- as.character(d$file)
  x <- fromJSON(json_str = as.character(d$responses)), what this d refers to? is it mispelled as "DF"? Anyway i've tried it with a "DF" but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in the dataframe (I've not done any "hard" operation to convert from json to R)

Comment: `d` is the argument to the anonymous function. If you are having problems you will need to provide a reproducible example that results in the error since the reproducible example in the answer does work as you can easily verify by copying and pasting it to your R session.

Comment: It works!! I was also replacing the "d" with the name of the database. Thank you a lot, i'd invite you for a dinner!